# Spring websocket (raw handler, not STOMP/SockJS) exception logging

Tags: java, spring, websocket

In a Spring application using raw websockets (by extending the class `TextWebSocketHandler`), exceptions thrown during handling of web socket events cause the connection to be closed with status 1011, but aren't appearing in my logs (using log4j version 2).  Is there an easy way to cause the exceptions that cause this action to be logged somewhere?  Do I simply need to change a logging option somewhere, or do I have to write an exception handling wrapper around my socket handler to make it work?  Or is there already such a wrapper I can just apply in my configuration?

Edited to add configuration details:

Relevant sections of my pom.xml file:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.version>4.3.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <log4j.version>2.7</log4j.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring core & mvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion> <!-- exclude commons logging so we can use SLF4J -->
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logging: SLF4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logging: SLF4J implementation of JCL API (required by Spring) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyMMdd'T'HHmmss} %highlight{[%t] %level{1} %logger{1.} - %msg%n%rEx{10}}"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

servlet-context.xml (only relevant sections):

```
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- websocket handlers -->
<bean id="roomServerSocketHandler" class="${package}.websocket.RoomServerSocketHandler">
    <!-- (properties removed) -->
</bean>

<!-- websocket handler mapping -->
<websocket:handlers allowed-origins="http://localhost:63342">
    <websocket:mapping path="/connect" handler="roomServerSocketHandler" />
</websocket:handlers>
```

Edit 2: have updated the maven config above because I've switched to SLF4J rather than commons-logging as my logging API for the project.  Previously it used the default commons-logging 1.2 dependency from Spring.  This hasn't changed the question, though.

Comment: can you add the code for current log4j and code on how you are logging ?

Comment: @javaguy - I'm  not currently doing any logging.  I have a basic spring MVC project with a single web socket handler, and have log4j-api, log4j-core and log4j-web on the classpath.  The only logging that is happening so far is the default Spring logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring has logging available, but the logging level for it is set to "debug".  Therefore, the following line is required in the log4j2.xml file, just above the `<Root>` logger declaration:

```
<Logger name="org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator" level="debug" />
```

Exceptions that cause a web socket to be closed are now logged, e.g.

```
161030T130445 D o.s.w.s.h.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator - Closing due to exception for StandardWebSocketSession[id=1, uri=/roomserver/connect]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The WebSocket session [0] has been closed and no method (apart from close()) may be called on a closed session
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.checkState(WsSession.java:803) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.getBasicRemote(WsSession.java:446) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketSession.sendTextMessage(StandardWebSocketSession.java:197) ~[spring-websocket-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ....
```